# How to use system proxy settings in Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, authentication, proxy, credentials

I have programmed an application in Python and implemented an auto update mechanism which just retrieves a text file from a cloud server and then checks the version number.

This works fine, but some subsidiaries have their proxies configured in a way that the cloud server can only be accessed through a proxy server.

Now, retrieving something from the web while using a proxy server is generally not a big deal.

I could just use something like this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.cloudserver.com/versionfile'
proxy = 'http://user:pass@proxyserver:port'
proxies = {'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}
requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

This works wonderfully. The problem is that I don't want my customers to enter username, password and proxyserver. Ok, I could get the username with getpass.getuser(), but not the password.

Another option that sounded promising was pypac:

```
>>> from pypac import PACSession
>>> session = PACSession()
>>> session.get('http://example.org')
<Response [407]>
```

Alas, it answers with 407 - Proxy Authentication Required.

There are professional programs out there which just magically use the system proxy settings including username and password (or maybe a hashed version or a ticket of some form) and never have to ask the user about anything. It just works, e.g. Firefox seems to do it that way.

Is it possible to extract or reuse the system settings to access the web without asking the user for the credentials in Python?